# Can you get upload progress when (multipart) uploading to S3 with only a presigned url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I would like to obtain the upload progress when doing multipart-upload to S3 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html). Buckets informations are private and I have only the presigned URL. Would it still be possible to leverage the S3 SDK to get accurate upload progress?

(I have tried using axio, XMLHttpRequest progress listeners, but they don't seem to work.)

If there isn't a way to do it just using the presigned url what would be a good way to estimate the upload progress?

Comment: The JS SDK has a ManagedUpload for this, but I'm not sure how it really works in the backend. Point is there should be a way to do so even if you only have the URL. If anything, worst case is manually using the number of uploaded parts vs total parts?